# How should I reply to "take care"?

Tags: conversation

What should I reply with when someone ends conversation with "take care" in online chats or in-person?

Comment: You, too. or u2.

Comment: *u2* is appropriate in informal chat if you and the person you're talking to commonly use abbreviations like *ur*, *l8r*, *cya*, *ofc*, *sry*, and so on.  Many people **don't** use these abbreviations, even in chat, so pay attention and avoid using them when it's inappropriate.

Comment: "You too" sounds kinda rude?

Comment: @SantoshKumar I don't think "you too" would ever be rude in response to "take care".  It's what I'd say.

Comment: @Santosh - I'd call it _casual_, not _rude_. While there may be a few situations where casual speech would be considered improper, those circumstances tend to be rare exceptions. In an online chat, I think "you too" would be quite safe.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing that "take care" is pretty much a standard phrase people use when ending a conversation, there are a host of ways you could reply:

- Bye!
- See ya!
- Hasta manana!
- Ciao.
- Toodles

That's half a dozen; we could probably come up with half a dozen more with very little effort.

There's really no best answer to this question. Perhaps you could pick two or three  responses that you feel comfortable with, and that you think reflect your personality, and tuck them away in your brain to be used when the time comes.

By the way, I've only known one person in my life that used *Toodles!* in this context consistently. But that made the phrase remarkably quaint and memorable. I suppose your choice depends on whether your want something that sounds quite standard, or something quirky and unique.

Comment: It may be noteworthy that "hasta manana" is spanish and directly translated means "until tomorrow", "see you tomorrow".
Is it common in english to use this phrase even if you do not see each other tomorrow?

Comment: @mr.gaussian It's not common in British English to use "hasta manana" at all. I've never heard it said, though I could believe it may be more common in American English.

Comment: @Sepia & Mr G. - Actually, it's not uncommon at all in the U.S., perhaps because there's a relatively significant segment of the population who are fluent in Spanish, particularly in many of the southwestern U.S. states. Moreover, Spanish is taught to many middle school and high school children in the U.S., so even many youngsters immediately recognize (and often use) a handful of catch-phrases such as _hasta mañana, buenos dias, adiós amigos_, etc.

Comment: There's a gal in our social circle who has been signing emails as "Toodles, Mary" for so long that we universally refer to her as Mary Toodles. [Names have been changed to protect the innocent. Or something.]

Answer (score 1):

I would just say

> And you! Bye.

Although I would omit the "And you!" if they say "Bye." after "Take care."

I hope this helps!